# Confugaration/steps needed when consuming external Restful service from Fiori front end server

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I have deployed a custom UI5 app ( using external REST ful services--> service hosted in another Java stack system) in the front end server.

I used Ajax to call the service directly with the URL as shown below.
This app has run successfully when i use "proxy" in local host(eclipse).

-->[Ajax Call code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyWTH.jpg)

So i replaced proxy with target url while deploying in front end. (http ://xxx.xxx:port)

When running from front end server i got cross origin error as shown below.

**Error1**:<http://xxx:port/xxx/ngservices/rest/query/ZQUE_WEBSERV_APPHISTORY/executeGet. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://xxx:port' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401>

After enabling CORS plugin in chrome i got unauthorised error as shown below.

**Error2**:<http://xxx:port/xxx/ngservices/rest/query/ZQUE_WEBSERV_APPHISTORY/executeGet. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401>

I got the above errors initally while running from localhost.After that i used proxy and it got solved.

I just deployed the app in frontend server and ran it directly. I haven't done any other configurations.

Do i need to do any extra configurations for consuming these external services or kindly suggest any other suggestions.

**Important info:**

*Able to call external service from localhost(eclipse--> used proxy here) but not able to call service from frontend server.

*Front end architecture: Central hub deployement and connected to SRM,HR and CRM backends currently.

Regards

Phani Poorna

Comment: Provide code please. From your calls e.g.

Comment: Its attached in the image above. Ajax code snippet

Comment: var settings = {"async": true,
      "crossDomain": true,
      "url": "http://xxx:port/xxx/ngservices/rest/query/ZQUE_WEBSERV_APPHISTORY/executeGet",
      "method": "GET",
      "headers": {
       "content-type": "application/json",
       "accept": "application/json",
       "cache-control": "no-cache",
       "authorization": "Basic xxxx", 
      }
    };
   $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {})

Answer (score 1):

Both of these errors can be solved by creating and configuring a destination on your platform.

A destination is essentially a proxy: when you create it, you specify the backend URL, the authentication mechanism (Principal propagation/basic authentication etc). From your client, you just need to then connect to your destination to query the backend.

What do you mean by Fiori front end server? Are you referring to the Portal service hosted on HANA Cloud Platform?

If so, then you can create a destination by going to Connectivity - Destinations from your HCP account. From your Fiori application, you then need to connect your destination using the following URL pattern:

```
/destinations/<destination name>/<whatever you want to add to the URL the destination points to>
```

If you are using a different PaaS, I'm sure it will have some similar way of creating a proxy between your client and your backend. *(Edit: I just saw you're using the Central hub deployment - I am not familiar with this system but it must have a very similar way of creating destinations).*

Hope this helps, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for the info.Its not HANA cloud platform. Its an on premise Central hub deployment where this front end system will be connected to multiple back end system with single aggregation point. Typically all the back ends will be ABAP stack(SAP systems).And OData services will be hosted on the front end server. But in our case our back end is JAVA stack(like a typical Non-SAP system). We have services hosted on back end itself. So i am directly calling that URL from the front end. So i wanted to know how the configuration need to be done.

Comment: Have you checked to see if you can find the equivalent of destinations on the onpremise hub?